# I'm trying to get live exchange rates into a sheet/cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-365

Excel 365 or excel V. 16.36 on a Mac. I'm trying to get live exchange rates into a sheet/cell.

My problems:

1. Cant seem to find the get from web option.
2. The menu in excel is not the classic, so cant find anything that we used to before, basically the classic menu with all options are missing.

Anyone know how to go about the above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows so may be different for you, but you can find the from web option on the data tab.

[image]

Please let me know if you do not have this layout on mac an di will remove this answer.

Or do you have the get data option ?

[image]

Comment: no, only from html, but doesn't let select a html file nor does it open the browser.

Comment: do you have the `get data` option ? see edit